# if i use jQuery syntax : $("<img src='img.jpg'>") , will the image actually be downloaded to the client?

Tags: jquery, syntax

if i use jQuery syntax : `$("<img src='img.jpg'>")` , will the image actually be downloaded to the client? or do i have to append it to body in order to download it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to add the image element to the document for the image to be loaded.

The image element itself will request the image as soon as you create it (and as soon as it has a `src` value).

Watch the net acivity (in Firebug/Developer Tools) when you run this: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/AvgVN/

[Google "javascript preload"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20preload) to find tons of code examples that uses this.

Comment: I thought this was wrong but it isn't! I now remember, the late '90s "image preloader" scripts also worked that way.

Comment: Me too. The fact is it is actually instantly downloaded!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the image will be downloaded immediately.

Even though the `Image` element that has been created isn't in the DOM yet, your browser will still start downloading it as soon as the `.src` attribute is set.

Using your own avatar, I just did this in the console:

```
> i = $('<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/100002351317104/picture?type=large">');
...
> i[0].width
180
```

showing that the image is indeed loaded.

If you think about it, this actually has to be the case otherwise image pre-loading could never work.  Image pre-loading depends on creating a detached `Image` node and setting its `src`, which is exactly what `$("<img src=...>")` will do.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, or maybe depends of browser.

```
$("<img src='http://crssrd.com/web_apps/index/themes/crssrd.com/images/loading.gif'>")​
```

Test this on Chrome for example: http://jsfiddle.net/SMnhU/
Image is instantly downloaded.

Comment: Can you provide an example where a browser _does not_ instantly download the image?

Comment: No, all browsers i've tested download it instantly. But i haven't tested opera for example but ill be really surprised if its different for this browser.

Comment: So perhaps it is safe to say that it _does not_ depend on browser :)

Comment: I would say its more safe to say 'maybe' than to assert something we are not sure